# Identifying a JavaScript Events Manager class or providing a simple alternative that does the same?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking through my Javascript and I found I'm using some javascript that helps add event listeners cross browser and cross platform but I don't know where I found it from or the license. Can anyone identify this code and the license? I've searched Google to the best of my ability and I did not get any results. But the funny thing is that's how I found it in the first place.

At the same time, if I don't find the owner or the license is incompatible is there an alternative simple, lightweight Event manager class I can use? Must use MIT or Apache 2.0 License.

```
var DocumentManager = {
    get: function(el) {
        if (typeof el === 'string') {
            return document.getElementById(el);
        } else {
            return el;
        }
    },
    add: function(el, dest) {
        var el = this.get(el);
        var dest = this.get(dest);
        if (!dest) dest = document.body;
        dest.appendChild(el);
    },
    remove: function(el) {
        var el = this.get(el);
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
};

var EventManager = {
    add: function() {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            return function(el, type, fn) {
                DocumentManager.get(el).addEventListener(type, fn, false);
            };
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            return function(el, type, fn) {
                var f = function() {
                    fn.call(DocumentManager.get(el), window.event);
                };
                DocumentManager.get(el).attachEvent('on' + type, f);
            };
        }
    }()
};
```

Comment: I wonder if this is off-topic... really not sure.

Comment: Is this *Google Pro*?

Comment: @KyleNeedham I don't think it is. It was on a blog but OTOH maybe it was inspired by it?

Comment: @Jashaszun My last comment made it sound like I was demanding something but it was a typo! Sorry! I meant to say I've updated the question to ask if someone can identify the code or provide an alternative. Thanks